# "Invalid Column Name" error in query with order by case statement and outer select

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, case

I am trying to order by a column in an outer select statement using a case statement to determine the fields to order by. For some reason, I cannot use the column created in the outer select. If I try to order by that column without using a case statement then it works. What am I doing wrong?

Pseudocode to illustrate problem:

```
DECLARE @orderBy varchar(8)
SET @orderBy = 'rating'

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN rating is not null THEN 1
        ELSE  0
    END as hasRating,
    *
FROM

(SELECT col1, ...) AS table1

LEFT OUTER JOIN

(SELECT col1, rating, ...) AS table2

ON table1.col1 = table2.col2

--causes error "Invalid column name 'hasRating'"
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'rating' THEN hasRating END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @orderby = 'something else' THEN ...

--works
ORDER BY hasRating desc
```

Comment: Can you also include the error?

Comment: @DavidStarkey: as I wrote in a code comment, the error is "Invalid column name 'hasRating'"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Does this throw an error:

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN @orderBy = 'rating' THEN CASE WHEN rating is not null THEN 1 ELSE  0 END END DESC,
    CASE WHEN @orderby = 'something else' THEN ...
```

Seems like the `CASE` in the `ORDER` by is evaluated before the alias is available.

Comment: You may also want to consider deriving the results 1 more time before ordering so you can use the alias you created instead of repeating the case statement.