# Order by calculated column with alias inside case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I've got a problem with my `order by` clause when using a calculated column with an alias as below:

This `order by` works without any problem

```sql
declare @Mode int = 1
declare @Sort nvarchar(max) = 'engname'

select top 10 School.Id          as EntityId,
              School.EnglishName as EntityEnglishName,
              School.Name        as EntityNativeName,
              case
                  when @Mode = 0 then 0
                  when @Mode = 1 then 1
                  when @Mode = 2 then 2
                  end as ActiveStudents
from V_SchoolMinimized as School
Order By ActiveStudents
```

The following query has an error:

> Invalid column name 'ActiveStudents'

```sql
declare @Mode int = 1
declare @Sort nvarchar(max) = 'engname'

select top 10 School.Id          as EntityId,
       School.EnglishName as EntityEnglishName,
       School.Name        as EntityNativeName,
       case
           when @Mode = 0 then 0
           when @Mode = 1 then 1
           when @Mode = 2 then 2
           end as ActiveStudents
from V_SchoolMinimized as School
Order By
    case when @Sort is null then School.Id end,
    case when @Sort = 'engname' then ActiveStudents end
```

How can I use `ActiveStudents` within the conditional `order by` clause as shown?

Comment: The alias is being evaluated before it's available: ["Invalid Column Name" error in query with order by case statement and outer select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18277782/invalid-column-name-error-in-query-with-order-by-case-statement-and-outer-sele)  Use a derived table.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8889c5479abf4c11e7d14e6b9468bcc6

Comment: @DaleK - The derived table is mentioned in the comments and the fiddle above, so I'm sticking with "dupe" :-)  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8889c5479abf4c11e7d14e6b9468bcc6

Comment: @mtdot please let me know how you get on.

Comment: I BELIEVE you can order by the ORDINAL COLUMN reference, such as order by 4

Comment: @drapp ordering by ordinal value is recommended against. And as far as I know if suffers that same issue as asked i.e. you can't combine it with other logic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So while you can use a calculated column in your `ORDER BY` clause (but not in other clauses such as `GROUP BY`), you cannot then apply further calculations or conditions - it must be used exactly as created.

There are a whole bunch of ways to solve this problem. Which approach you use will come down to some combination of:

- Which option is clearer to you as the developer
- Which option performs better
- Which option fits into your existing query better

**Option 1: Repeat the logic**

I don't recommend this option because it violates the DRY principle thereby making it harder to maintain and easier to make mistakes.

```
select top 10
    S.Id as EntityId
    , S.EnglishName as EntityEnglishName
    , S.[Name] as EntityNativeName
    , case
          when @Mode = 0 then 0
          when @Mode = 1 then 1
          when @Mode = 2 then 2
      end as ActiveStudents
from V_SchoolMinimized as S
order by
    case when @Sort is null then S.Id end
    , case when @Sort = 'engname' then
        case
            when @Mode = 0 then 0
            when @Mode = 1 then 1
            when @Mode = 2 then 2
        end
    end;
```

The rest of the options are sub-query variations the choice of which comes down to the comments provided as the start.

**Option 2: Use a derived table sub-query**

```
select top 10
    S.Id as EntityId
    , S.EnglishName as EntityEnglishName
    , S.[Name] as EntityNativeName
    , S.ActiveStudents
from (
    select *
        , case
              when @Mode = 0 then 0
              when @Mode = 1 then 1
              when @Mode = 2 then 2
          end as ActiveStudents
    from V_SchoolMinimized
) as S
order by
    case when @Sort is null then S.Id end
    , case when @Sort = 'engname' then S.ActiveStudents end;
```

**Option 3: Use a CTE (Common Table Expression)**

```
with cte as (
    select *
        , case
              when @Mode = 0 then 0
              when @Mode = 1 then 1
              when @Mode = 2 then 2
          end as ActiveStudents
    from V_SchoolMinimized
)
select top 10
    S.Id as EntityId
    , S.EnglishName as EntityEnglishName
    , S.[Name] as EntityNativeName
    , S.ActiveStudents
from cte
order by
    case when @Sort is null then S.Id end
    , case when @Sort = 'engname' then S.ActiveStudents end;
```

**Option 4: Use `CROSS APPLY`**

```
select top 10
    S.Id as EntityId
    , S.EnglishName as EntityEnglishName
    , S.[Name] as EntityNativeName
    , A.Students
from V_SchoolMinimized as S
cross apply (
    values (
        case
            when @Mode = 0 then 0
            when @Mode = 1 then 1
            when @Mode = 2 then 2
            end
    )
) as A (Students)
order by
    case when @Sort is null then S.Id end
    , case when @Sort = 'engname' then A.Students end;
```

Note: I suggest keeping your table aliases nice and short, 1-2 characters where possible, occasionally 3.

Comment: Or you could just wrap it in `(` and `)` and make it a derived table, so the alias is available in the order by clause.

Comment: Yep. Since the execution plan for cross apply's is often more expensive than alternatives, I prefer to avoid it when there are other readable alternatives.

Comment: It is, and results vary a lot depending on the query and volume.  For literals, it may make no difference, but [here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71714923/display-percentage-of-registered-members-that-have-not-rated-a-movie/71722134#71722134) where cross apply is more expensive than at first glance. Agreed a better dupe probably exists, but I'm too sleepy to find one right now!

Comment: I'm using cross apply and it works perfectly. Thank you very much!